# Unknown argument type '__attribute__' in method RCTAppState. Extend RCTConvert to support this type

Tags: react-native-ios

Got the following error running a react-native app on iOS:

```
Xcode 11 Error: "Unknown argument type '__attribute__' in method -[RCTAppState getCurrentAppState:error:]. Extend RCTConvert to support this type."
```

Answer (score 4):

Solution taken from [here](https://appdevblog2019.blogspot.com/2019/07/xcode-11-error-unknown-argument-type.html):

This is a 0.59 version bug.

Edit the following file:

```
react-native/React/Base/RCTModuleMethod.mm
```

Add in line 94:

```
RCTReadString(input, "__attribute__((__unused__))") ||
```